# Entity Framework - how do I use the entity associations?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-relationship, associations

When I have tables in my database that have PK/FK relationships (int) and when they are modeled by the Entity Framework designer everything seems as it should be.  I can write the code below and everything seems like it's going to work fine as well but then when I run the code I get an error on the project.Status.StatusName saying the Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I guess I was under the impression that the framework populated the associated entities when you populate the parent entity.

```
    Dim db As New MyDbModel.MyDbEntities()

    Dim project As MyDbModel.Project = (From p In db.Project Where p.ProjectID = 1).First

    Response.Write(project.ProjectName)        
    Response.Write(project.Status.StatusName)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using Include(RelationshipName)

```
Dim db As New MyDbModel.MyDbEntities()    
Dim project As MyDbModel.Project = (From p In db.Project.Include("Status") Where p.ProjectID = 1).First    
Response.Write(project.ProjectName)            
Response.Write(project.Status.StatusName)
```

Comment: I have a follow up question that I've posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384138/entity-framework-how-do-i-use-the-entity-relationships-in-my-extended-classes

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework does not load related entities unless you tell it to. In order to access related entities you need to either Load() them explicitly or use Include(). Here's a short sample.

http://blogs.msdn.com/bethmassi/archive/2008/12/10/master-details-with-entity-framework-explicit-load.aspx