# Entity Framework - how do I use the entity relationships in my extended classes?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-relationship, partial-classes

I am trying to extend the partial classes that the entity framework creates so that I can more easily work with objects like in the code below (please let me know if there's a better or more exceptable way of doing this with the entity framework)

```
    Public Sub New(ByVal ProjectID As Integer)
        Dim proj As Project = (From p In db.Project.Include("Status") Where p.ProjectID = ProjectID).First
        _ProjectID = proj.ProjectID
        _ProjectName = proj.ProjectName
        Me.Status.StatusID = proj.Status.StatusID  'I get errors here
        Me.Status.StatusName = proj.Status.StatusName  'and here
    End Sub
```

But of course I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the line: Me.Status.StatusID = proj.Status.StatusID

How can I pass through the related entity values when extending the partial classes?  Or am I just way off base here and there's a much easier way of doing what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your trying to load the object based on the id from the construtor

I personally wouldn't use the constructor to load the object, you can either use a shared function or use LINQ directly in your code to load your object.

use something like

```
Public Shared Function GetProjectById(ByVal ProjectId as Integer) as Project
     Dim db As New MyDataContext
     Return (From p In db.Project.Include("Status") Where p.ProjectID = ProjectID).FirstOrDefault
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks!  now if I can just figure out how to insert update and delete I'll be set! haha

Comment: Its much easier than you may think.  just create a new project call db.AddToProjects(project) and say db.SaveChanges